# Projectors and idempotents

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, linear-algebra, specific-calculation

An $n\times n$ matrix $P$ (over a commutative ring with identity $R$) is called a *projector* if $P^2=P$.

Let $X$ denote the $\mathbb{Z}$-affine subscheme of $\mathbb{A}^{n^2}$ that is defined by the vanishing of the entries of $P^2-P$ and let $\mathcal{O}(X)$ denote its coordinate ring.

**Problem**: Write down the idempotents in $\mathcal{O}(X)$ that split $X$ into connected components according to the rank of the projector.

When $R$ is a *domain*, the rank $r$ of such a matrix lies in the set $[0,n]$ of integers between $0$ and $n$. In fact, the "characteristic polynomial" $f_P(x)=\det(x+P)$ of $P$ is one of the polynomials $(x+1)^kx^{n-k}$, where $k$ is the rank of the matrix.

It follows that a necessary and sufficient condition for $P$ to have rank $k$ is:

**Condition for rank $k$**: The coefficient of $x^{n-k}$ in $f_P(x)$ is $1$ and all *higher* degree coefficients are $0$.

Note that this works over *any* domain regardless of characteristic.

For $k=1,\dots,n$ we define the elements $a_k$ in $\mathcal{O}(X)$ so that
$$
    \det(x+P) = x^n + a_1 x^{n-1} + \dots + a_n = x^n + \sum_{k=1}^n a_k x^{n-k}
$$
By induction on $k$ we define $e_n=a_n$ (for $k=0$) and (for $k\geq 1$):
$$
    e_{n-k} = (1 - e_n - \dots - e_{n-k+1}) a_{n-k}
$$
One can perhaps prove (using induction) that $e_{n-k}=1$ if and only if the above condition is satisfied. Hence, if and only if the rank of the projector is $k$.

**Claim**: The elements $e_{n-k}$ of $\mathcal{O}(X)$ are the required idempotents.

**Question**: Is there a "direct" computational proof that $e_k$'s are an orthogonal system of idempotents in $\mathcal{O}(X)$?